# Error: undefined local variable or method 'var' for top-level

Tags: crystal-lang

I am new to the crystal programming language.

Whenever I run this code:

```
var = ARGV.find { |x| x.split(".").size == 4 } || "0.0.0.0"

ARGV.delete(var)
Addr = var.split(".").map { |x| x.to_i { 0 } }.join(".")
p Addr
```

With crystal, I get an Error:

```
Showing last frame. Use --error-trace for full trace.

In q.cr:4:8

 4 | Addr = var.split(".").map { |x| x.to_i { 0 } }.join(".")
            ^--
Error: undefined local variable or method 'var' for top-level
```

But whenever I omit the last line `p Addr`, or replace `var` with `Var`, the code seems to work fine.

Crystal Version:

```
Crystal 0.31.1 (2019-10-21)

LLVM: 9.0.0
Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little gotcha that we hopefully will get better error messages for in the future.

So the first piece to this puzzle is to understand that `var` is a local variable because it starts with a lowercase letter and `Addr` is a constant because it starts with an upper case letter.

For reasons constant initializers, so the code after the `=` sign in an constant assignment, are run lazily the first time the constant is accessed. Because of this they exist in their own scope and cannot reference the local variable defined in the top level scope.

So there's three ways out of this for your example. First making `Addr` a local variable too by calling it `addr`. Second promoting `var` to a constant by calling it `Var`. Or third putting your entire code into the constant initializer:

```
Addr = begin
  ip = ARGV.find { |arg| arg.count('.') == 3 } || "0.0.0.0"
  ARGV.delete(ip)
  ip.split('.').map { |part| part.to_i { 0 } }.join('.')
end
```

Which of the three is best depends largely on taste and the structure of your program.